# How to URL encode this so I can pass it to Facebook Share?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, encoding

This is the URL I want to share:

```
http://mydomain.com/#url=http://stackoverflow.com
```

Inside my site, I do this in Django so that everything will work:

```
http://mydomain.com/#url={{external|urlencode}}
```

However, when I pass it to Facebook Share, everything gets messed up.

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<url to share>&t=<title of content>
```

I tried to  urlencode the #url part, and also the full url, but it's not working, and my #url is not holding up when there are `& and ?` signs everywhere.

Comment: can you clarify what happens? What is "messed up"?

Comment: could you accept an answer or clarify if the problem remains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is, that you first urlencode the last part of url, which you then include into another url.

try use `urllib` for that:

```
import urllib
urllib.quote("http://mydomain.com/#url=http://stackoverflow.com")
```

or when you have to unquote something:

```
urllib.unquote("http%3A//mydomain.com/%23url%3Dhttp%3A//stackoverflow.com")
```

kind regards